# grunt-angular-templates write templates into a separate file

Tags: javascript, templates, build, gruntjs, grunt-usemin

I'm using ng-templates and usemin in my app and I would like to write my angular templates into a separated file, so I created a usemin block reference to it in my `.html` file, like so:

```
<!-- build:js(.) scripts/templates.js -->
<!-- endbuild -->
```

I configured the ngTemplates task with these options:

```
ngtemplates: {
  dist: {
    cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>',
    src: ['**/*.html'],
    dest: '.tmp/templateCache.js',
    options: {
      module: 'myTemplateModule',
      htmlmin: '<%= htmlmin.dist.options %>',
      usemin: 'scripts/templates.js'
    },
  }
}
```

But I just figured out that `scripts/templates.js` file is not created, probably because the html build block is empty, so the templates don't get written into the file.

Any advice about how to make this work would be nice.

Answer (score 2):

In what order are you calling the tasks? I've found that the `usemin` option for `ngtemplate` will only work if you call it *after* the `useminPrepare` task, but *before* any of the `usemin` generated tasks have been called. I.e. your task should look something like:

```
grunt.registerTask('build', [
  //preliminary tasks...

  'useminPrepare'
  //unrelated tasks...
  'ngtemplates'
  //unrelated tasks...
  'concat:generated' 
  //etc.

])
```

Doing that results in the template file being generated, but `usemin` won't insert it into the final html unless you have at least one file in the block. I'd suggest putting the file containing the template module declaration in the block reference, like in the following:

```
<!-- build:js(.) scripts/templates.js -->
<script src="path/to/module/templates.module.js"/>
<!-- endbuild -->
```